# Allow all incoming ICMP connections internal network iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to allow all incoming ICMP connections from the internal network using iptables, but somehow it won't allow it.

I've added the following rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0 -d 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
```

If also tried to alter the second rule to:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Have a look to https://www.crybit.com/iptables-rules-for-icmp/ this will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to allow it for everyone, try to specify the mask after the IP address.

from:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0 -d 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
```

to:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

This worked for me.